# How to create an ISO image from a bunch of files on the file system?

Tags: iso, cd-image

Considering I have a bunch of files in a directory, I would like to bundle them into an ISO image file. How should I proceed to do that?

Answer (score 112):

Few quick steps:

1. Boot up Linux.
2. Go to a terminal screen. You can usually right click on the desktop and choose this option from the drop-down menu.

   3A. Type `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=~/cdrom_image.iso`.

   OR

   3B. Type `mkisofs -o /tmp/cd.iso /tmp/directory/` To make an ISO from files on your hard  drive.

You **must** have permission to access the drive directly using `dd`. `mount` permissions are not necessarily the same as `dd` permissions!
Also... when creating an ISO file, the device must not be mounted. To unmount the cdrom device, use the `umount` command as follows:

> umount /dev/cdrom

You may also use `sudo` to ensure you have proper permissions, but this also means you must have `sudo` access on the system. Check the `/etc/sudoers` file for information.

Comment: Step 4 is the **correct** solution to the original question. `sudo` should not be required for this. Remember to move `cd.iso` to whatever folder Wine/PlayonLinux needs for installation!

Comment: "4 type "mkisofs -o /tmp/cd.iso /tmp/directory/" To make an ISO from files on your hard drive." worked greatly, thanks

Comment: No problems , thanks to approve it as an answer !Glad to help

Comment: To preserve long file names, `mkisofs -r -o /tmp/cd.iso /tmp/directory/` (enables Rock Ridge protocol).

Comment: do you need step 4 if you are ripping files from a cdrom?

Comment: @don.joey No, only one of step 3 or 4 is required. I edited the answer to label them as 3A and 3B, and added an "OR" in between.

Comment: These methods don't create a bootable iso file from a bootable DVD, for example. I tried to create an iso image from a DVD with Windows 7 and tried to load it on Virtual Box, but it didn't work.

Comment: To have long file names in Windows, the -r is not enough, and you need to add a -J also (for Joliet), so `mkisofs -r -J -o /tmp/cd.iso /tmp/directory/`.

Answer (score 71):

It's easy to create ISO in terminal as described in other answers but there are some GUI options too, Like Brasero. If you don't already have it, you can install it using:

```
sudo apt install brasero
```

**How can I create ISO images with Brasero?**

- Hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (Windows key) and search for "brasero" and open it.
- Click on the <kbd>Data project</kbd> button.

  [image]
- Click on the green plus button in the upper left corner in the toolbar to start adding files and directories to your image:

[image]

- Enter the name of disc at the bottom to whatever you like.
- Make sure no empty CD/DVD is in your optical drives and click on Burn.
- Brasero will ask you for the location where you want to create ISO image, Give your desired location and click on <kbd>Create Image</kbd>. That's it!

If you want to burn that image to disc, Just right click on ISO image you just created and select "Open With Brasero Disc Burner". Select your optical drive and click <kbd>Create Image</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't create a bootable iso file from a bootable DVD, for example. I tried to create an iso image from a DVD with Windows 7 and tried to load it on Virtual Box, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 34):

Try This:

Go to the Terminal

Type `genisoimage -o ~/backup.iso -V BACKUP -R -J ~/Documents`

or, for more useful permissions, change -R to -r:
`genisoimage -o ~/backup.iso -V BACKUP -r -J ~/Documents`

In this case Ubuntu will generate a file called "backup.iso" with all the contents in the Documents Folder.

http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3513

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Might want to mention that `-V  volid` specifies the volume ID / name / label, and how it's apparently randomly called "BACKUP" here, unrelated to the question

Comment: link is dead now

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer

Comment: The link lives forever in Wayback: https://web.archive.org/web/20140115063003/https://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3513

Comment: `-l ` is typically preferred since it will preserve the filenames instead of shrinking filenames to 8.3 notation. https://linux.die.net/man/1/genisoimage

Answer (score 19):

I actually had to do this just today. A really easy way to do it is in the terminal, so type:

```
cat [device file of external disk] > ~/newfile.iso
```

To find the device file of the external disk open up the Unity launcher and search for "System Monitor," then go to "File Systems."

So an example would look like:

```
cat /dev/scd0 > ~/newfile.iso
```

Comment: The question was how to create an .iso from files contained in a .zip, not from an actual disc.

Comment: +1 The speed of cat astounded me.

Comment: this is amazing! I can't believe how easy this is

Answer (score 15):

Actually, there is a very simple answer to this question. I have just created **Windows 7 ISO** file with no problems. Didn't really liked the Brasero method because it keep throwing pop-up windows. It had some compatibility issues with file names and ISO standard. I believe this method is compatible with Mac OS ISO's as well.

This answer is provided by using Archive Manager, the default archive manager in Ubuntu 14.10.

Open your folder with files you want to include in ISO.  Then select `view/show hidden files`, select all files , right click and choose `compress...`

[image]

On new window select ISO option, file name and location. That's it!

Comment: This no longer works on Ubuntu 19.10.  They have dumbed down the compress options so that you only have 3 choices none of which is .iso.

Comment: Is there any way to enable this again ? It was very helpful and one of the most used feature of archive manager.

Comment: The ISO option is still available, just not in the simplified context dialog. Read the Archive Manager solution proposed by Ishan Jawade

Answer (score 2):

Making ISO file feature is already there in Ubuntu as VRR said in his answer. To elaborate more read this.

Open Archive Manager.

[image]

Open the folder to which you wanted to convert an ISO file.

[image]

Copy all the content from the folder to Archive Manager including hidden files.

[image]

Click on Create Archive and select .iso as an extension.

[image]