# How to burn a .dmg file to a DVD/CD?

Tags: burning

I have downloaded Mac.OSX.Mountain.Lion.v10.8.3 and I have never burned a dmg file. How to burn this operating system in a dvd?

Comment: it's 5gb, you can't burn it to dvd, you have to use usb, unless you have some special dvd, what is the size of your dvd?

Comment: hey i have double dvd of 8.5gb

Comment: Can you select the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands:

1. Install [`dmg2img`](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dmg2img
   ```
2. Browse the folder where the file is located:

   ```
   cd PATH/TO/THE/FILE
   ```
3. Next convert the `.dmg` to `.img`:

   ```
   dmg2img NAMEOFTHEFILE.dmg NAMEOFTHEFILE.img
   ```
4. Create a directory to mount the image:

   ```
   mkdir /media/image
   ```
5. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo modprobe hfsplus
   ```
6. Mount the image:

   ```
   sudo mount -t hfsplus -o loop NAMEOFTHEFILE.img
   ```

   /media/image
7. Download Brasero:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install brasero
   ```
8. Create the `.iso` with from the previously mounted `.img` following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/136416/110936) guide.
9. Open Brasero and burn the image (`.iso`).

This is quite simple and you should get no troubles at all. Good luck.

Comment: Command-line method for burning to disc [here](https://bleedux.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/burn-isoimg-image/)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install dmg2img
```

convert dmg to iso

```
sudo dmg2img yourdvd.dmg yourdvd.iso
```

install dvd writing software in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wodim
```

list your dvd device and note it down

```
wodim --devices
```

write your iso to dvd

```
wodim dev=/dev/cdrw -v -data yourdvd.iso
```

Comment: `$ wodim --devices
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices'`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any dmg to iso, according to [this tutorial](http://dailytechnologiesupdate.blogspot.de/2011/11/converting-dmg-to-iso-file-in-ubuntu.html).

After that, you can handle the file like you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is:

```
dmg2img example.dmg example.iso
```

Comment: The ISO file that came out of my 4.7 GB DMG is too big to fit on a DVD, it's 5.1 GB now.