# I want to make a DVD with video_ts and audio_ts folders into an mp4/avi/video file

Tags: video, files, dvd

I have a collection of DVDs with audio_ts and video_ts folders that have a menu where you select chapters, etc., and I want to watch these movies on my phone. I move movies to my phone using the VLC app, so they have to be in video format. How do I do this?

Comment: As far as I remember The Audio_ts folder have newer been used in commercial products, and if you investigate your own DVD's you will see that this folder is empty ( it was supposedly meant for High Quality sound recordings (like flag or ogg vorbis formats) but it newer became popular, hence newer commercially available - to our sadly loss!
Video_ts folder is only supported up to MP2 format, same as the old cable tv strreams.
All sounds on a DVD is included in the video_ts folder (CD or lower quality sadly!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handbrake seems like a suitable solution for your needs if you want to transcode the movies and make them smaller in size.

You should be able to install it from Ubuntu's Software Center or you can install it from the terminal by typing the following (if sudo asks for a password enter the one of the user you're currently logged in with):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

Depending on your distribution you might not get the latest version, so you may want to install it through Handbrake's PPA by typing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

**//EDIT:**

If you want to keep the menus you could make the DVD as a .iso file which should be played by VLC for Android (I have no idea about iPhone).
Creating .iso files from DVD is already discussed on the site, you could take a look at one of these topics for example:

[How to create ISO images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136165/how-to-create-iso-images)

[Ripping DVD to iso - Accurately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147800/ripping-dvd-to-iso-accurately)