# Start game without CD with wine

Tags: wine, games, cd-drive

recently I installed a game on my Notebook PC which runs problemless with wine.
But I don't want to carry the CD everywhere around e.g. if i travel with the bus.

Has anyone an idea how to run the game without CD? For example *simulate* a CD-drive on my Notebook, from where I could start an ISO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ISO images?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136165/how-to-create-iso-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an image and mount it.
Create iso with app like brasero or with dd from command line, as described here: [How to create ISO images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136165/how-to-create-iso-images) 
Then mount it with `mount` command as described here: [How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file)