# Create a Windows ISO from windows boot files

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, iso

I want to repair my windows installation, I am using ubuntu22.04 and I have been dual booting with windows with Grub (Ubuntu) as my primary bootloader. But windows was somehow broken and needs to be repaired. I have windows installation files which used to work on windows when I formatted my USB with NTFS and copy the them. But that won't work on ubuntu I want help creating a .iso file from those windows installation files, so I can create a bootable USB to repair or reinstall windows. I would download new windows iso image file, but it's too big for my internet.

Comment: this covers all you ask: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136165/how-to-create-an-iso-image-from-a-bunch-of-files-on-the-file-system it even had a method for w7 but that does no longer work it seems. Use https://askubuntu.com/a/136182/15811 and take note of the comment about long names

Comment: You cannot use dd with Windows ISO. Newer Windows ISO has a .wim file that is too large for FAT32 which is required for UEFI boot. The Windows tool to create bootable flash drive splits .wim file. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu? Or if old BIOS install, then install a Windows type boot loader like syslinux to directly boot Windows? Often multiple reboots & f8 will get Windows to try to fix itself. But always best to have repair flash drives or live installers for current versions of all installed systems.

Comment: I ended up downloading windows isolated file from Microsoft website and using ventoy to boot from USB